# Dockerfile build inconsistency in a Jenkinsfile (Connection failed error)

Tags: docker, jenkins

In my Jenkins CICD pipeline, I have stage where I build my backend image.

```
stage('Build Backend Image') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    docker login -u <id> -p <pw> <dockerhub>
                    docker -v
                    docker build \
                    --label com.build.stage=3 \
                    -f ./backend/Dockerfile \
                    -t <dockerhub>/back_stage_1:build .
                '''
                sh "docker tag <dockerhub>/back_stage_1:build <dockerhub>/ack_stage_1:${GIT_COMMIT}"
            }
    }
```

The Dockerfile tied to this stage looks like:

```
#Using ubuntu as our base
FROM ubuntu:latest

#Install commands in ubuntu, including pymongo for DB handling

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-dev build-essential


#Unsure of COPY command's purpose, but WORKDIR points to /backend
COPY /backend/ /backend
WORKDIR /backend/

RUN pip3 install requirements.txt

#Run order for starting up the backend
# ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["python3", "-u", "app.py"]
```

Just a simple Dockerfile that installs the dependencies.

This step sometimes works fine but sometimes gets stuck.

The error that I am getting looks like:

```
Step 5/11 : RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-dev build-essential
 ---> Running in ba358993dc8b
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
...
...
0 upgraded, 135 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 117 MB of archives.
After this operation, 390 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 liblocale-gettext-perl amd64 1.07-3build2
  Connection failed [IP: ...]
```

It just keeps giving me Connection failed error until I abort it.

When it works, it just successfully installs all packages and goes through the entire steps successfully.

I don't understand because it's too inconsistent and fails even though I did not change anything in the Dockerfile or Jenkins. I feel like it has something to do with some Jenkins' trait that I don't know.

Any help?

Comment: See if you can get a more verbose output from apt-get and inspect further?

Comment: I'm going to suggest your internet connection is a little flaky; maybe a proxy or similar is misbehaving under heavy use. Try the same from a different location (e.g. home) and see if you get the same issues. This might help narrow down the issue.